# How to mark up recurring events with Schema.org for Google?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm using schema.org to mark up a page for a local business and I have a weekly (mon-thurs) recurring event that I'd like to send metadata on.

I've looked around the internetz and cannot seem to find any answers as to how I can properly mark this up. I did what a Google user group suggested by using `openingHours` even though I knew it wasn't part of the `Event` schema.  Google called me on it of course.

Any suggestions as to how I can tag this?

I'm happy to change it to a different type if that works, though I am unsure as to what I could change it to. For reference, [here is the page in question](http://mudbugspub.com/index.php).

**UPDATE** I looked a bit into the `Event` type a bit more and found something called `subEvent`.  Schema.org also says that "Repeated events may be structured as separate Event objects." but how on earth I can achieve this is beyond me.
The main problem lies in the fact that the recurring event is largely undefined.  It is just Mon-Thur, every week, for an indefinite period of time, so it makes no sense to try and give a bunch of actual dates like Thurs July 10, Tues July 15, etc.

**followup**
If schema.org has no solution, are there any other microdata formats out there that could?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, there is only the solution to create separate `Event` items for each recurrance, as described in [its definition](http://schema.org/Event):

> Repeated events may be structured as separate Event objects.

Related links:

- Mailing list thread: [Proper schema.org markup of repeating / recurring events?](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2011Dec/thread.html#msg60)
- Wiki page: [WebSchemas/RepeatingEvents](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/RepeatingEvents)
- Issue: [Schema.org should say how to describe repeating events](http://www.w3.org/2011/webschema/track/issues/11)

In the mentioned thread, [Martin Hepp lists advantages](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2011Dec/0062.html) of creating separate `Event` items for *each* single event:

- easier for consumers to query the data when each date is set explicitly
- you can model exceptions (cancelled, rescheduled or delayed events)

Comment: I could go with the hcalendar but I would really rather stick with one microdata format for all of my markup.  I am familiar with schema.org but unfamiliar on other standards (and how widely recognized by search engines they are).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, schema.org does not yet have a mechanism to mark up recurring events, at least not easily.  You would have to basically mark up each event separately.  But I noticed that your website does have an entertainment calendar, so that would be the perfect page to mark up all of the restaurant's events.  And as a suggestion, you should use schema.org/Restaurant as the main entity/schema type, and then nest the various events within it.  In that way, you wouldn't have to mark up the restaurant's name and location for each unique event.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about using Restaurant.  I stuck with LocalBusiness because this place is a restaurant during the day but does more business as a bar, so I have to keep it a little generic, since there currently us no type for a hybrid like this business is

Comment: I understand.  In that case, you might want to go with schema.org/FoodEstablishment, as Restaurant and BarorPub are more specific types of the FoodEstablishment type.  That type at least lets search engines understand what kind of business it is in a general sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

You can now use the new evenSchedule type to define recurring events :)

See https://schema.org/eventSchedule

Comment: Keep in mind that just because this is on the schema it does not mean it is for practical use. Google does not support this for example

Answer (score -1):

it would be good to follow a current working example. it should define start and end period event it actually undefined. first of all, let's see example as follows.

[1. eventful.com event list page which has itemtype="http://schema.org/Event"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pZ7L.png)

```
http://london.eventful.com/events
```

[2. google result displays a structured data from that website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0lJI.png)

```
https://www.google.co.jp/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=P6ARWaG0NrLK8geA0ozgCw&gws_rd=ssl#q=eventful.com+local&spf=1
```

here is a HTML of that event "les miserables". as you can see this code has some structured data format attribute "itemtype".

```
<div 
class="event card plu" 
itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" 
itemscope="" 
data-ga-action="Event Cards" 
data-href="http://london.eventful.com/events/les-miserables-/E0-001-036914463-9@2017050919" 
data-sid="E0-001-036914463-9@2017050919">
<img src="http://s3.evcdn.com/images/perspectivecrop373by249/I0-001/004/156/822-3.jpeg_/les-misrables-22.jpeg">
<a 
    class="card_link" 
    href="http://london.eventful.com/events/les-miserables-/E0-001-036914463-9@2017050919" 
    itemprop="url" 
    data-ga-label="PLU Card Link">
</a>
<div class="info">
    <h3 itemprop="name">
        <!-- check if item is PLU then add icon and link to learn -->
        <a title="" class="plu-link" href="http://eventful.com/advertise/learn" data-ga-label="Promote Events Link" data-original-title=""></a>
        <a href="http://london.eventful.com/events/les-miserables-/E0-001-036914463-9@2017050919" data-ga-label="Title Link">Les Miserables</a>
    </h3>
    <p class="details" itemprop="startDate" content="2017-05-09T19:30:00">Tue, May  9 -  7:30 PM</p>
    <p itemprop="location" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" itemscope="">
        <a class="details venue" href="http://london.eventful.com/venues/queens-theatre-/V0-001-001363468-4" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="name">Queen's Theatre</span>
        </a>
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
</div>
<a class="bn bn-sz-sm modernize bn-orange click-tckt-link" href="http://london.eventful.com/events/les-miserables-/E0-001-036914463-9@2017050919/tickets" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-ga-label="PLU Ticket Button" source="fet" data-lid="fet" data-spot="homepage_card">Find Tickets</a>
```

root itemtype is itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" as an attribute of div.

event name comes from 
you can find start date "Tue, May  9 -  7:30 PM

".

to follow such example, structured data should work.

old answer:

you can find examle site which is listing events using google richsnippet.

tacoma dome calendar 
support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164506?hl=en

let's see how the site "eventful.com" looks like in google structured data testing tool.
www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fseattle.eventful.com%2Fvenues%2Ftacoma-dome-%2FV0-001-000144232-7

events are under the type of "eventvenue".
I tried same structure and worked.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.